# Will DDR2 667 & DDR2 533 work together in Intel D946GZIS?

Tags: memory, ddr2

My motherboard is Intel D946GZIS. It supports up to 4 GB RAM. I'm having a 1 GB DDR2 533 MHz RAM in it now. I want to add 2 GB RAM to it. But DDR2 533 MHz RAM is not available in nearby retail stores. If I buy a 2 GB DDR2 667 MHz RAM and use it with my 1 GB DDR2 533 MHz RAM, will it work fine? It's okay if the 667 MHz RAM will clock to 533 MHz and give me 3 GB in total. But I don't want a scenario in which only one of the RAM can be used at a time.

This is the Motherboard specification document: http://downloadmirror.intel.com/15108/eng/D946GZIS_SpecUpdate05.pdf

This is the RAM I'm planning to buy: http://www.transcendusa.com/support/dlcenter/jetram/product/pdf/jm667qlu-2g_2980-s.pdf

Some expert advices please..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work fine, the DDR2-667 RAM module will downclock to the lower frequency.

Answer (score 1):

The Intel document you note shows no combination of RAM modules that give 3GB of RAM.  The system does seem to support downclocking of the faster module.

Comment: The last configuration listed (512MB smallest usable DIMM; 2GB largest usable DIMM) can give you 3GB of total RAM if you use one 1GB stick + one 2GB stick.

Comment: The configurations given are only using identical DIMMs. The OP is trying to use two DIMMs of different capacities.

Comment: @Indrek: The _maximum_ is based on 2 identical x8 double-sided DIMMs (because double-sided DIMMs can be bigger), but there's nothing in the PDF that says you need to use the same size for both sticks.

Comment: @Lèsemajesté My comment was aimed at Dave M. Sorry if that wasn't immediately obvious.

Comment: @Indrek: Doh! I totally misread that. =P